# SQL server export data to csv break line

Tags: sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I'm using `SQL server 2008`
I wrote a batch that exports store procedure resultes into csv file:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer -d MyTable -E -Q "dbo.MySPname" -o "c:\\textfile4.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 999 -W
```

1.
When I open the output csv file I saw a break line in the middle of the row, like:

```
[Row 1]
[line 1]:  col1_val, col2_val, col3_val, [line break]
[line 2]:  col3_val,....

[Row 2]
[line 3]:  col1_val, col2_val, col3_val, [line break]
[line 4]:  col3_val,....
```

2. And there are now headers.

**Whats wrong with my export?**

Answer (score 1):

It was a line break in one of the fields
I solve that by adding

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```